# Project last value in a series to future cells in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 2-column dataframe that has 365 rows for every date of the year. This dataframe gets populated as data comes in every day. I want to create another column that outputs 1) historical data for any row that actually has data, i.e. date < today; and 2) yesterday's data for any row that doesn't have actual data, i.e. date >= today.

Say today's date is May 5, 2019:

```
Date           Actuals     Projection
05/01/2019     2           2
05/02/2019     7           7
05/03/2019     8           8
05/04/2019     4           4
05/05/2019     1           4
05/06/2019     0           4
05/07/2019     0           4 
05/08/2019     0           4
05/09/2019     0           4
05/10/2019     0           4
```

I've tried a convoluted combination of `where` and `loc` but it's not working as expected:

```
df['Projection'] = where(df['Date'] < date.today(),df['Actuals'],df.loc[df['Date'] == date.today() - timedelta(days=1),['Actuals']])
```

Any idea how I could go about this?

Comment: By "doesn't have data" do you mean it's 0, or is the check just on the date really?

Comment: The check is just on the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `where` + `ffill`

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df['Projection'] = df.Actuals.where(df.Date.lt('2019-05-05')).ffill().astype(int)

        Date  Actuals  Projection
0 2019-05-01        2           2
1 2019-05-02        7           7
2 2019-05-03        8           8
3 2019-05-04        4           4
4 2019-05-05        1           4
5 2019-05-06        0           4
6 2019-05-07        0           4
7 2019-05-08        0           4
8 2019-05-09        0           4
9 2019-05-10        0           4
```